# consul health check using script is not validating

Tags: consul

on my consul server and other nodes, I added 3 checks for CPU Utilization, memory utilization and hdd utilization. I don't know why they failing during validation. what am I doing wrong.

```
{
  "retry_join": [
    "172.20.20.31"
  ],
  "data_dir": "/tmp/consul",
  "client_addr": "0.0.0.0",
  "checks": [
    {
      "id": "check_cpu_utilization",
      "name": "CPU Utilization",
      "script": "/vagrant/provision/hc/cpu_utilization.sh",
      "interval": "10s"
    },
    {
      "id": "check_mem_utilization",
      "name": "MEM Utilization",
      "script": "/vagrant/provision/hc/mem_utilization.sh",
      "interval": "10s"
    },
    {
      "id": "check_hdd_utilization",
      "name": "HDD Utilization",
      "script": "/vagrant/provision/hc/hdd_utilization.sh",
      "interval": "10s"
    }
  ]
}
```

and if I validate the consul config file.

```
consul validate common.json                             
Config validation failed: Error parsing common.json: 3 errors occurred:
    * invalid config key checks[0].script
    * invalid config key checks[1].script
    * invalid config key checks[2].script
```

my consul version is 1.8.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to define script checks is using the [`args`](https://www.consul.io/api-docs/agent/check#args) parameter in the check definition.

```json
{
    "id": "check_cpu_utilization",
    "name": "CPU Utilization",
    "args": ["/vagrant/provision/hc/cpu_utilization.sh"],
    "interval": "10s"
}
```

The examples on the [Check Definitions](https://www.consul.io/docs/discovery/checks#multiple-check-definitions) page also show the use of the `args` field.